# UserControl's DataContext update WPF

Tags: wpf, user-controls, wpf-controls

I have my own usercontrol named FlashControl in the mainwindow. I set the DataContext by following code  in the mainwondow

```
        (FlashControl.Content as FrameworkElement).DataContext = null;
        (FlashControl.Content as FrameworkElement).DataContext = this.DataContext;
        FlashControl.DataContext = this.DataContext;
```

My problem is whenever my datacontext change I need to call the above code to reset usercontrol's datacontext. Why Usercontrol's DataContext not updated automatically when main DataContext change? How to do automatic update? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want automatic update dont set DataContext directly but Bind it to the value you want.
You should bind in xaml but if you want to do in code behind then you can do:

```
Binding myBinding = new Binding("DataContext");
myBinding.Source = this;
BindingOperations.SetBinding(FlashControl, FrameworkElement.DataContextProperty, myBinding);
```

Comment: @@nit How to do the same in xaml?

Comment: @RobinAtTech [creating-a-binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-binding-overview?view=netdesktop-5.0#creating-a-binding)